# Eclipse custom template parameterized based on trigger keyword

Tags: java, eclipse

I want to create a custom template with substitution default values based on the trigger keyword.  For example `for100` should give output

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {

}
```

Is there any way to parse `${word}` to get `100` and substitute it into the generated code?

The best I am able to do is:

```
for (int ${index} = 0; ${index} < ${cursor}; ${index}++) {

}
```

But this does not do modify the code based on the keyword.

Comment: `Preferences:Java/Editor/Templates`

Comment: @JimGarrison yes, tried that? but how to get that `100` from my word?

Comment: y the downvote :/

Comment: Ah, your question was not clear. No, you cannot parameterize a template from a variation of the trigger keyword.   I have updated your title to indicate what you're asking.

Comment: Not possible anyhow? maybe using plugin ? or custom variable

Comment: Did you find the [documentation](http://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Fconcept-template-variables.htm)?

Comment: Doesn't look like I can manipulate them.